# ifelse not returning a vector in BASE R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Maybe this is too basic of a question. But in my function `foo` below, I expected that because of using `ifelse` when I input a vector for the input values, I get a vector output.

But I wonder why in the example below instead of getting `> [1] 1   6` in the output, I just get `> [1] 1` as the output?

```
foo <- function(mpre = NA, mpos = NA, mdif = NA){
ifelse(!is.na(mdif), mdif, ifelse(!is.na(mpre) & !is.na(mpre) & is.na(mdif), mpos - mpre, NA))
}
## EXAMPLE:

foo(c(1,3), c(2,9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` returns output of same length as input (`test`). From `?ifelse`

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test

Since `mdif` is of length 1 it returns output of same length i.e `[1] 1`. Use `if` for scalars and `ifelse` for vectors.

```
foo <- function(mpre, mpos, mdif = NA){

   if(!is.na(mdif)) mdif 
     else ifelse(!is.na(mpre) & !is.na(mpre) & is.na(mdif), mpos - mpre, NA)
}

foo(c(1,3), c(2,9))
#[1] 1 6
```

Comment: Yes, but don't forget the warning. It says `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` which tells you it checks only first value.

Comment: Perhaps `!is.na(mpre) & !is.na(mpre)` is redundant (or a typo)?

Comment: I guess it is redundant or was it supposed to be `!is.na(mpos)` ?Not sure I just copied OP's function as it is.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
 foo <- function(mpre, mpos, mdif = NA){

  if(!is.na(mdif)) mdif 
    else ifelse(!(is.na(mpre) | is.na(mpre)) & is.na(mdif), mpos - mpre, NA)
    }

  foo(c(1,3), c(2,9))
```